# String.Format or native function to format ABCDEF -> ABC-DEF

Tags: .net

I have a string and want to add some hypens in the middle. I know I can use Substring or something, but want to be sure that I can not use `String.Format` or other native function to do the job.

```
String.Format("{0:###-###}", "ABCDEF"); //  <-- does not work
```

Comment: if abcdef are all digits, there are things you can do. otherwise, not so much

Comment: @Joel: ok, I take the word from you, you surely have points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the Insert method from string such as below

```
Console.WriteLine("ABCDEF".Insert(3, "-"));
```

You can work out the insert position instead of hard coding above by simply divide the length/2

Answer (score 0):

There's no "standard" way to know where a hyphen might go there, so you're going to have to provide instructions about where it goes (likely using `Substring()`).

You can use `Format()` in conjunction, though:

```
string startStr = "ABCDEF";
string result = string.Format("{0}-{1}", startStr.Substring(0,3), startStr.Substring(3));
```

Comment: Right, but the formatting you can specify applies to spacing and (for numbers) significant digits/scientific notation/etc. If you want a dash in an arbitrary place in a string, you need more than `Format`.